# Intent to choose between specific leaderboards

Tags: android, google-play-games

To show a leaderboard in android with google play games you can show one with `.getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id))` or you can show a menu to the user with all the leaderboards defined in your games proyect with `.getAllLeaderboardsIntent()`

My question is, can you show a menu like the one with `.getAllLeaderboardsIntent()` but limiting the leaderboards the user can choose from?

Comment: This is totally related to your business logic. Please be more specific hen you asking a question on StackOverflow. Could you please update your question with some more related information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible at the time being.